# nodejs garbage collection in worker threads appears to perform differently than in main thread

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads

I am using some image processing libraries in nodejs like [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) and [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp), I wanted to put them in a worker thread as they are cpu intensive. However, it seems when using these tools on large images, nodejs worker threads never garbage collect.

I have been able to reproduce the issue with the simplest of all operations on the large source files, that being to read them into a buffer with fs read.

The following code snippet shows that the size of rss keeps increasing indefinately when the `bigFileTest()` is executed within the worker, but does garbage collect when executed in the main thread.

The following things have been attempted:

- Forcing garbage collection initiation with `global.gc()` With node option `--expose-gc`) makes no difference.
- Providing time for gc to perform it's function using `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));` makes no difference.
- Setting a limit on max old space makes no difference `--max-old-space-size=1024`
- explicitly setting the `fileBuffer` variable to null makes no difference

The example below gets a large file from wikipedia and then loads it into memory 10 times within a loop in the service worker. The memory used increases by the size of the file on every iteration.

However, if the example is executed calling the test from main thread, the memory utilised does not increase.

Is there any way to trigger garbage collection within the thread. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import path from "path";
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

import {
    Worker,
    isMainThread
} from 'worker_threads'

import {readFile, writeFile, access} from "fs/promises";


const moduleURL = new URL(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(moduleURL.pathname);
const __filename = moduleURL.pathname;


if (isMainThread) {
    await ensureBigFileExists()
    const worker = new Worker(__filename);

    //await bigFileTest()
} else {
    await bigFileTest()
}


async function bigFileTest() {

    let bigFileName = "Google_Art_Project.jpg"
    let imagePath = path.join(__dirname, bigFileName)
    let priorRss = process.memoryUsage().rss
    let baseRss = process.memoryUsage().rss

    let iterations= 10

    for (let iterator = 0; iterator < iterations; iterator++) {
        let fileBuffer = await readFile(imagePath)
        fileBuffer = null

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
        global.gc()

        let diff = Math.round((process.memoryUsage().rss - priorRss) / 1024 / 1024 * 1000) / 1000
        priorRss = process.memoryUsage().rss

        let rssMem = Math.round((process.memoryUsage().rss - baseRss) / 1024 / 1024 * 1000) / 1000
        console.log("iteration:", iterator, "mem:", rssMem, "avg:", Math.round((rssMem) / (iterator+1) * 1000) / 1000, "diff:", diff, JSON.stringify(process.memoryUsage()))
    }

    let diff = Math.round((process.memoryUsage().rss - priorRss) / 1024 / 1024 * 1000) / 1000
    priorRss = process.memoryUsage().rss
    let rssMem = Math.round((process.memoryUsage().rss - baseRss) / 1024 / 1024 * 1000) / 1000
    console.log("out of context:", "mem:", rssMem, "avg:", Math.round((rssMem) / (iterations+1) * 1000) / 1000, "diff:", diff, JSON.stringify(process.memoryUsage()))


}

async function ensureBigFileExists() {
    let bigFileUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg"
    let bigFileName = "Google_Art_Project.jpg"
    let imagePath = path.join(__dirname, bigFileName)

    try {
        let fileBuffer = await access(imagePath)
    } catch (error) {
        let fetchResponse = await fetch(bigFileUrl)
        let buffer = await fetchResponse.buffer()
        await writeFile(imagePath, buffer)
    }
}
```

## Results

### When executed in worker

note that the rss size keeps incrementing up by roughly the size of the file being loaded.
However, heapTotal and heapUsed appear to not increase.

```
iteration: 0 mem: 205.254 avg: 205.254 diff: 205.254 {"rss":275357696,"heapTotal":10432512,"heapUsed":4017872,"external":217147950,"arrayBuffers":215130045}
iteration: 1 mem: 410.199 avg: 205.1 diff: 205.078 {"rss":489996288,"heapTotal":7286784,"heapUsed":4014224,"external":432214297,"arrayBuffers":430194808}
iteration: 2 mem: 611.043 avg: 203.681 diff: 201.152 {"rss":700858368,"heapTotal":7548928,"heapUsed":3964488,"external":647279060,"arrayBuffers":645259571}
iteration: 3 mem: 815.637 avg: 203.909 diff: 204.887 {"rss":915390464,"heapTotal":6762496,"heapUsed":3773128,"external":862343823,"arrayBuffers":860324334}
iteration: 4 mem: 1020.715 avg: 204.143 diff: 205.078 {"rss":1130430464,"heapTotal":7286784,"heapUsed":3818600,"external":1077408586,"arrayBuffers":1075407961}
iteration: 5 mem: 1225.738 avg: 204.29 diff: 205.023 {"rss":1345413120,"heapTotal":7286784,"heapUsed":3855704,"external":1292473349,"arrayBuffers":1290464372}
iteration: 6 mem: 1431.215 avg: 204.459 diff: 205.535 {"rss":1560608768,"heapTotal":7548928,"heapUsed":3904560,"external":1507538112,"arrayBuffers":1505518623}
iteration: 7 mem: 1636.289 avg: 204.536 diff: 205.023 {"rss":1775906816,"heapTotal":7548928,"heapUsed":3941224,"external":1722602875,"arrayBuffers":1720591450}
iteration: 8 mem: 1841.816 avg: 204.646 diff: 205.527 {"rss":1991417856,"heapTotal":7811072,"heapUsed":3999456,"external":1937667638,"arrayBuffers":1935680549}
iteration: 9 mem: 2046.406 avg: 204.641 diff: 204.59 {"rss":2205945856,"heapTotal":7548928,"heapUsed":4037768,"external":2152732401,"arrayBuffers":2150743584}
out of context: mem: 2046.098 avg: 186.009 diff: -0.309 {"rss":2205622272,"heapTotal":7548928,"heapUsed":4483000,"external":2152732401,"arrayBuffers":2150712912}
```

### when executed in main

```
iteration: 0 mem: 208.23 avg: 208.23 diff: 209.145 {"rss":266444800,"heapTotal":11247616,"heapUsed":5534672,"external":216195798,"arrayBuffers":16578}
iteration: 1 mem: 194.699 avg: 97.35 diff: -9.531 {"rss":250159104,"heapTotal":8101888,"heapUsed":5413024,"external":216197670,"arrayBuffers":16578}
iteration: 2 mem: 202.133 avg: 67.378 diff: 11.434 {"rss":260050944,"heapTotal":8101888,"heapUsed":5406288,"external":216197670,"arrayBuffers":16578}
iteration: 3 mem: 198.969 avg: 49.742 diff: -1.164 {"rss":256733184,"heapTotal":8101888,"heapUsed":5261632,"external":216197670,"arrayBuffers":16578}
iteration: 4 mem: 205.285 avg: 41.057 diff: 8.316 {"rss":263356416,"heapTotal":8364032,"heapUsed":5271176,"external":216197670,"arrayBuffers":16578}
iteration: 5 mem: 205.938 avg: 34.323 diff: -1.348 {"rss":261943296,"heapTotal":8364032,"heapUsed":5269520,"external":216197670,"arrayBuffers":16578}
iteration: 6 mem: 204.23 avg: 29.176 diff: 0.293 {"rss":262250496,"heapTotal":8364032,"heapUsed":5277112,"external":216197670,"arrayBuffers":16578}
iteration: 7 mem: 204.934 avg: 25.617 diff: 2.703 {"rss":262987776,"heapTotal":8364032,"heapUsed":5273936,"external":216197670,"arrayBuffers":16578}
iteration: 8 mem: 201.645 avg: 22.405 diff: -1.289 {"rss":259538944,"heapTotal":8364032,"heapUsed":5302160,"external":216197670,"arrayBuffers":16578}
iteration: 9 mem: 205.996 avg: 20.6 diff: 4.352 {"rss":264101888,"heapTotal":8364032,"heapUsed":5303280,"external":216197670,"arrayBuffers":16578}
out of context: mem: 7.234 avg: 0.658 diff: -198.762 {"rss":55685120,"heapTotal":8364032,"heapUsed":5553128,"external":216197670,"arrayBuffers":16578}
```

Comment: FYI, your call to `global.gc()` is probably less useful than it could be because `fileBuffer` for that iteration of the loop is still in scope when you call it.  What is the exact output you see in the console?  It would be best to also check the memory usage some period of idle time after everything is complete.  My experience is that calling `global.gc()` does not accomplish everything that simply waiting after some idle time will sometimes accomplish.

Comment: Also, an actual leak can only be seen with `.heapUsed`.  Once allocated heap memory, but no longer used and garbage collected for reuse may not be returned to the system so would still show in `.rss()`.  In other words, garbage collection may or may not reduce the value of `.rss()` - that really depends upon the type of allocation and whether it's something that can be easily returned to the OS or not.  Whereas `.heapUsed` shows memory actually in use by the interpreter and the delta between `.heapTotal ` and `.heapUsed` represents the portion of the allocated heap available for reuse.

Comment: I have no idea why it would behave differently in the worker vs main thread, but since the worker shares process memory with the main thread (both in the same process), it is perhaps a bit confusing to understand exactly what is getting reported with some of the metrics.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the post to include the console logs. Thank you for the hint that ```.rss()``` many not include the impact of garbage collection. I note that ```.heapUsed``` is not increasing.  So it appears that the worker is not notifing main of the rss impact of garbage collection.

Comment: Also, my system monitor shows memory usage increasing consistent with what rss would state... and eventually the worker and node terminate with a memory fault.

Comment: So, it looks like the issue is not with regular Javascript garbage collection at all since neither the `.heap` or the `.heapUsed` shows continual growth.  But, `.arrayBuffers` is getting bigger every time.  This is memory from allocated Buffer objects which are probably the ones used by `readFile()` and `writeFile()`.  If this is regularly reproducible with just the code you show here, I don't see any coding reason for that problem so it would be a bug you should probably file.  Also see this existing bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34703 which might or might not be related.